# Join tables with one known variable in second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have a problem with my SQL query.

Situation is as follows:

I have two tables, A and B.

Table A:

```
---------------------------------------------
*| A.id  |  A.t_id  |  A.f_id  |  A.type    |*
---------------------------------------------
 |   1   |    32    |     3    |   Loading  |
 |   2   |    34    |     5    |  Discharge |
 |   3   |    32    |     3    |  Discharge |
---------------------------------------------
```

Table B:

```
-----------------------
*| B.id  | B.shipid |*
-----------------------
 |   1   |    1     |
 |   2   |    1     |
 |   3   |    2     |
-----------------------
```

I need all the rows from A where A.type=Loading, A.t_id is B.id -> B.shipid=2 and . My query so far is:

```
SELECT *  FROM A, B WHERE  (A.type='Loading' AND B.shipid=2 AND A.t_id=B.id)
```

but this doesn't return the right records (none, actually) while the data should fit the query. Where does my query goes wrong?

Comment: Why do you expect results? How can `32` or `34` be equal to `1`, `2` or `3`?

Comment: Should it not be `where A.f_id = B.id`?

Comment: I would highly recommend that you invest some time getting to grips with the ANSI standard join syntax. Listing tables in the `FROM` clause is a recipe for total disaster as you can't distinguish your  join conditions from your filter criteria in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: +1 @DMK seems like it.. looking at the sample data.. and likewise ypercube..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this::

```
SELECT 
*  
FROM 
A
INNER JOIN B ON A.t_id=B.id

WHERE  A.type='Loading' AND B.shipid=2
```

Comment: Why would this return any different results from the OP's query?

Comment: I have absolutely no clue why my query didn't work, but this did! Thank you very much, I've accepted the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM A a JOIN B b ON a.t_id = b.id WHERE b.shipid = 2 AND a.type = 'Loading'
-- a and b are aliases for A and B. If you have any bigger table names, it's useful
```

And you should lookup `SQL JOIN` http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you need all rows from A then it sounds like a left join... so please also provide your expected results anyway to confirm..

```
SELECT A.*  FROM A
INNER JOIN B 
ON A.f_id=B.id
AND A.type='Loading' AND B.shipid=2
;
```

Since you have a condition to get records for loading, and the only issue is that id aren't matching as per the above comments pointed out..

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/528c5/3)